# Dashboad type app for iPhone

Tags: iphone-app, dashboard

Anyone know of any interesting dashboard type apps for the iPhone; specifically iPhone 6?

I'm using the following apparatus to arrange my phone next to my Macbook:

[image]

Thinking of an app to actively update me on a variety of things (Twitter, news, custom feeds, etc.). Closest thing I found was [Panic's Dashboard app](https://www.panic.com/statusboard/), but that's not available on the iPhone.

Comment: I've installed Panic's Prompt. `SSH`'d into server and ran `htop`. Thinking i'm going to install a terminal based dashboard ...